# How can I import a TMX file via API Memsource?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to upload a TMX (= XML) file to Memsource server using API request but my code's always failing with # 400 Error (Bad Request).
How can I fix this issue?
I very much hope on your assistance!

References:

- Memsource API documentation (Translation Memory\Import TMX section):
  https://cloud.memsource.com/web/docs/api

P.S.: I am using Python 3.11

The code is:

```py
import codecs
import requests

f_name = r'D:\my_folder\myTranslationMemory.tmx'
token = 'ApiToken ABCDEFG123'
transMemoryUid = 'myTransMemoryUid'
url = 'https://cloud.memsource.com/web/api2/v1/transMemories/' + str(transMemoryUid) + '/import'

headers = {'Authorization': token,
           'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename="{f_name}"',
           "Content-Type": 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8'
           }

with codecs.open(f_name, "rb", encoding='utf-8') as tmx_fileobject:
    file_dict = {f_name: tmx_fileobject}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=file_dict)
    print(response)
```

The error is:

> <Response [400]>

Comment: Another error that I keep receiving is UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position ...: ordinal not in range(256). Which of these two errors occur depends on an input file I feed to my script.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Now it works.

```
import codecs
import requests    

f_name = r'D:\my_folder\myTranslationMemory.tmx' 
token = 'ApiToken ABCDEFG123'

transMemoryUid = 'myTransMemoryUid'
url = 'https://cloud.memsource.com/web/api2/v2/transMemories/' + str(transMemoryUid) + '/import'
headers = {'Authorization': token,
           'Content-Disposition': f"attachment; filename*=UTF-8\'\'{f_name}",
           'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
           }

with codecs.open(f_name, "rb", encoding='utf-8') as tmx_fileobject:
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=tmx_fileobject)
    print(response)
    print(response.text)
```